# Mirroring Windows 11 screen to MacOS over local WiFi

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, macbook, windows-11

I need to mirror the entire screen of a Windows PC to a MacBook over local WiFi. It would be great if I can do things on the Windows PC through the MacBook, but it's not entirely necessary.

It should be a windowed version of the screen (or be able to switch to other apps on the MacBook) so that the MacBook doesn't become a TV, and is still usable for work.

I need:

- The Mac to be able to use other apps while being able to see/switch to the Windows screen.
- The Windows PC to be able to do things while it's being watched.
- The solution to be relatively simple to follow and set up.
- The solution to either be low cost or preferably free.
- I have Windows 11 home, so remote desktop will not work.

Comment: I would suggest VNC

Comment: Or the Microsoft remote desktop client for macOS.

Comment: @jimtut I have windows 11 home, meaning I cannot enable Remote Desktop. I have edited the question to include this information, thanks